# My Bank WILL NOT accept TOR... For past 3 months

Tags: configuration

My Bank...  stopped opening with Tor since Ver 5.5. and still does not work with Ver 6.0...

It does connect ... but will not display the page.  Then upon  retry, get a Tor error that says Server takes too long to connect.

Im a novice with Tor... User..not developer.

What data do I need to find to send along for anaylsis?
The full path is ... https://www.regions.com/personal_banking.rf

BTW all my other sites work fine... eg... Fidelity.com, Capitalone.com, , Optumrx.com, etc...

Also BTW.. inorder to have safari to access Tor.com, I had to disable my DNS

Comment: It's entirely possible they are blocking (dropping) packets from Tor exit relays.  Since you said it stopped working in 5.5, does this mean you can still access it from earlier versions of Tor browser?  What about running Tor independently of Tor browser and configuring a current Chrome or Firefox browser to use Tor's SOCKS proxy?

Comment: I don't have expertise to try the valuable suggestions from Drew010. Actually it has been not working prior to ver 5.5.5.    I would like to try his idea..never ran Tor except from its browser...i ' ll do some research and try with my Chrome browser...  Many thanks for reply...

Comment: If you're willing to tell me your bank website, either here or privately, I'd be happy to give it a try for you.  Since I'm set up, it doesn't take more than a minute.  For Windows, you're looking at the Tor expert bundle, which lets you run a Tor daemon, or on Linux, you can quickly install Tor via your distribution's package manager which will give you a Tor daemon, typically running SOCKS on port 9050, which you can then configure any SOCKS capable application to use.

Comment: I didn't see the domain in the post.  My best guess is that regions.com is blocking Tor at the network level.  I even tried a bunch of US based exit relays and none of them could connect (they simply time out).  I could see the DNS being resolved, it just fails to connect.  And I can access other sites over the same circuits.  So I would contact them and see if there's anything they can do.  But you may be limited to using a VPN to connect if you want to do it from an IP other than your own.

Comment: The site is as I stated in my first post....

Comment: Sorry...   It is ....   https://www.regions.com/personal_banking.rf.   Please let me know what you see... Jim B

Comment: I don't use a VPN on my iMac ...OS X .. I do use a VPN from my iPad running iOS 9.3.2... It works fine accessing the bank URL above.   ...it also works fine on iPad w/o the VPN.. Of course, Tor cannot be used by the OS in IPad...

Comment: Yeah I think they're blocking Tor.  See the 4th comment.

Comment: I called bank tech  support. They have stopped supporting any Firefox browser. ...guess that is why ..I'm stuck!   Jim B

Comment: Is there a rather easy way to use Tor w/o Firefox? I might try if I knew how.

Comment: And... My iPad browser is a modified Safari...it is part of 1PW management system. I use that system for all iPad access. Also use it on OSX ...

Comment: But I have not installed a VPN on OSX....know of a good on Earth? The iOS version I use on iPad is ONAVO...Jim b

Comment: It has nothing to do with firefox.  I was not using FF when testing over Tor.  They're blocking Tor at the network level.

Comment: Is there a specific explanation I can use at the tech support ?  Something I can point to that explains the blocking?  Not sure these types are very knowledgable about the transport layers...?

Comment: I doubt any support people you can call would have any clue, or the channels to report it.  Best bet might be to email them from the general contact form asking why the recently started blocking Tor.  Since it's largely to mitigate risk, it may be hard to make any change.  Though they can implement additional security controls instead of full on blocks.

Comment: Many many thanks for your replies. I will send in a request for why they are blocking Tor.